Is quantum computation effectiveness dependent on EPR non-locality?
Suppose 100 qubits are used to perform a quantum algorithm.
According to the EPR view, each of these 100 qubits already have pre-determined states before we start the computation, which are just unknown to us.
Does this automatically break all powers of quantum computation, if each of these 100 qubits already have pre-determined states in the beginning (which can nevertheless be modified, polarization reversed, etc.) throughout the computation stages?

No, because there's no need for the hidden-variable theory to be easy to simulate. It doesn't help at all to have everything pre-determined if it's computationally expensive to follow the evolution. A simple example is a quantum computation that has a deterministic answer; then you can take the deterministic hidden-variable theory to be quantum mechanics itself, and we know that regular Schrödinger evolution is exponentially expensive to simulate (in the number of qubits).
Now, if you require your hidden-variable theory to be local then it might necessarily be easy to simulate, because the state space won't be able to grow so fast. But since local hidden variable theories can't reproduce quantum mechanics anyway the question is moot.

The best known example of non-local hidden variable theory is Bohmian mechanics. It doesn't really have a value for the polarization of a photon, what it can tell you is what the result will be when you do a polarization measurement. Since the theory is non-local, you need to specify the state of the entire universe to know it.

Yes. Some Bohmians postulate though that this knowledge is impossible to obtain, as it would allow dramatic deviations from quantum mechanics.

Normal quantum mechanics is a non-local hidden variable theory. The state vector is the non-local hidden variable.

Quantum mechanics is arguably non-local, but calling it a hidden variable theory requires some violence to the common understanding of this expression: there's nothing hidden about the state vector, and moreover hidden variable theories are usually required to be deterministic.

Well, it's not local. And it's almost entirely hidden; you can only extract n bits from a 2^n sized state vector. I suppose the main thing I forgot to mention is you have to throw a PRNG to decide on the measurement results; then you've got yourself a deterministic non-local hidden variable theory consistent with observation. It might even be the most common one used in practice, since that's what state vector simulators typically use as their implementation.
